# How to alter command being run by drush_invoke?

Tags: hooks, drush

When you run `drush features-revert-all` command, it can be altered using [`hook_drush_command_alter`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/function/hook_drush_command_alter/8.0.x) (`&$command`).

However during run it's invoking another command by:

```
drush_invoke('features-revert', $features_to_revert);
```

It seems I can still use `drush_hook_pre_COMMAND` and `drush_hook_post_COMMAND` to perform some additional checks.

However I'd like to alter the list of arguments (features) being passed into `features-revert` which are not available as part of the main command.

Is there any [Drush hook](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/8.0.x) which I can use to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drush calls command hooks via the function [_drush_invoke_hooks](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/includes/command.inc#L366), which unfortunately does not provide any facility to alter the arguments list from a pre or validate hook.  We are looking to provide a [more flexible mechanism that would allow this](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2103) in Drush 9. Currently, only the command alter hook can change the parameters to a command. Ideally, Drush commands should invoke other Drush commands via `drush_invoke_process`; this will also go through the command alter hook.  If a command uses drush_invoke, though, you are stuck, as `drush_invoke` bypasses the alter hook.